# How can we find the path of trace files

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I write this code in oracle developer but I get error

```
SELECT   VALUE FROM    v$parameter       WHERE NAME = 'BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST';
```

I get this error :

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 17
```

how can fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting from v$diag_info, it has all the information you may need.
As for the error, it is probably because the user you're logged in does not have the privileges to query v$parameter, and you need to check the parameter name, it should be lower case.

Comment: I write GRANT SELECT ON v$PARAMETER TO   users TEST ;
  but i get error : ORA-00933

Answer (score 0):

1. The error "table or view does not exist" doesn't always mean obbject does not exost in the DB. It also might say that you have no access. To check whether the object exists in the DB you need to query the following

   ```
   select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'OBJECT_NAME_BIG_LETTERS';
   ```

If object is there, you just have no righs to access it

In your case the user just can't reach the V$PARAMETER and you need to GRANT it:

```
grant select on v$parameter to USER;
```

2. Trace files

Another way to get path to traces is either by querying v$process or v$diag_trace_file

FYI: The v$diag_trace_file_contents gets you the contents of trace files

Comment: but I write the code for grant but I get error :ORA-00987

Comment: @secretgirl2023 it means username does not exist or is wrong. Just double check whether there is a typo in the command.

Comment: I write GRANT SELECT ON  v$parameter  TO  USERS; but I get the same error , please help me . I do not TIME , I must fix It .please help me .

Comment: I get error :ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action: when I write : GRANT SELECT ON  v$parameter  TO  USERS;

Comment: @secretgirl2023  Not sure if "USERS" is the real user name. You need to specify a real user's name. Like "GRANT SELECT ON v$parameter TO scott" or something of that kind

Comment: The grant should be done when connected as SYS (or another DBA). And if you use the v$diag_info, you don't need the grant.

Comment: @secretgirl2023 - it sounds like you're trying to go the `grant` as the same user that can't see `v$parameters`. You can't grant privileges to yourself - that would make them a bit pointless. You need to run that as a privileged user, or get your DBA to run it for you or give you a privileged role (and they may object); or ask your DBA to tell you where the files are or provide them to you; or to give you access to `v$diag_info`, `v$diag_trace_file`, `v$diag_trace_file_contents` etc. instead if you're using ADR.